# Cast void* to struct*

Tags: c++, c, struct, casting

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    UINT8 a;
    UINT8 len;
    BYTE *data;
} MyStruct;
```

and this binary array [0x00, 0x03, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a] which is assigned to a void* variable "BINDATA".

How can I cast BINDATA to MyStruct and be able to access its "data" field?

I tried:

```
MyStruct *myStruct = (MyStruct*) BINDATA;
```

After that I was able to access:

```
myStruct->a; //gave me 0x00
myStruct->len; //gave me 0x03
```

But I could not access

```
myStruct->data;
```

without memory access violation. I guess this is because "data" address pointer gets set to 0x08 and not its value.

Comment: What is ```myStruct->b```? in your struct I cant see b member.

Comment: Undefined behavior for accessing an object through an lvalue not of the effective type of the object.

Comment: What is `myStruct->data` supposed to be? What is the correct result for this example?

Comment: It is C++ but I wonder if it can be done in C too.

Comment: `myStruct->data` shall be a pointer to BYTE with following contents: `0x08, 0x09, 0x0a`

Comment: It's doable with some changes to MyStruct and some packing directives, but the way it is now, you would have to make a new MyStruct and set the pointer to the correct address for "data", as well as initialize the other values.

Comment: Are you sure pointers are 24 bit on the given system? 16, 32 or 64 bit pointers are much more common.

Comment: Show code saving a struct to BINDATA and loading from it. It must be error there.

Comment: This violates [strict aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), and so EOF is right in that it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `BYTE *data` you should use `BYTE data[0]` or (if your compiler doesn't like this) `BYTE data[1]`. The difference between pointer and array here is crucial - array is "data that is right here" while pointer is "data somewhere else" which is not your case.

Comment: Wow this actually works. But isn't that a little hacky? It looks weird in the code to define data[1];

Comment: @arminb, not at all. You're just putting data in an array, which is OK.

Comment: @arminb It's called a "flexible array member". It's allowed in C, but not in C++.

Comment: @Barmar how do you mean it's not allowed? How do you do this in C++?

Comment: @arminb In C, you declare the flexible array member with an empty size `BYTE data[]`. That's what isn't allowed. If you declare it with a size, nothing stops you from allocating more space with `malloc()` and writing more elements. But the language doesn't address the proper way to calculate the additional size.

Comment: Also C++ `new MyStruct` can't be used to allocate larger space.

Comment: In C++ you can use `(MyStruct *) ::operator new(sizeof(MyStruct)+len)`

Answer (score -1):

Something like this may work in c++:

```
UINT* a1 = &myStruct->len;
UINT* a2 = ++a1;
```

Then cast a2 to whatever you want.
Be aware of the size and the type of your data.